# How to load slow parts of a website later?

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, client-server

I have a web application, where a user request can trigger a calculation which takes some time. I would like to deliver the skeleton of the website immediatly, while i deliver the slow parts later. With which techniques this is usally achieved?

In my case, I have a Google App Engine application in python, which make a call to the twitter API, analyzes the result and displays it to the user. This takes 2 seconds or so and I don't want the user to wait for such a long time. How can I let the Get-Handler deliver the Skeleton early and let the client load the analysis reuslts when they are ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key for this is [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). With it you can query your server for parts of the page and add them dinamically whenever they're ready.

Comment: Here is a nice [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkddK0Rd7nA) for incorporating AJAX with App Engine